# Repeating values in loop until error disappears

Tags: r, loops, error-handling, try-catch

I am currently using a for loop to geocode a large number of addresses using the Googleway package. Initially, I ran into issues with "500 internal server errors" stopping the execution of the loop. I was able to get around this using tryCatch(). However, since this tends to be a transient error, I would like the function to repeat the address that throws the error until it receives a result or hits some arbitrary number of attempts, let's say 10.

Unfortunately, I've found tryCatch() and the documentation associated with it confusing, so I'm at a loss for how to do anything other than get it to throw an error message and move on. Here is my current code:

```
rugeocoder.fun <- function(addr){
              require(googleway)
              output <- vector("list", length=length(addr))
              tryCatch({
                for(i in 1:length(addr)){
                  output[[i]] <- google_geocode(address=addr[i], key="myapikey", language="ru", simplify=T)
                  print(i)

                }},error=function(e) output[[i]] <- "Error: reattempt")
              return(output)
              }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to separate out the logic for calling `google_geocode()` safely, and for looping over the addresses.

Here's a function that modifies other functions to call them repeatedly until they work, or they fail `max_attempts` times.  Functions that modify other functions are sometimes called "adverbs".

```
safely <- function(fn, ..., max_attempts = 5) {
  function(...) {
    this_env <- environment()
    for(i in seq_len(max_attempts)) {
      ok <- tryCatch({
          assign("result", fn(...), envir = this_env)
          TRUE
        },
        error = function(e) {
          FALSE
        }
      )
      if(ok) {
        return(this_env$result)
      }
    }
    msg <- sprintf(
      "%s failed after %d tries; returning NULL.",
      deparse(match.call()),
      max_attempts
    )
    warning(msg)
    NULL
  }
}
```

Try it out on this simple function that generates a random number, and throws an error if it is too small.

```
random <- function(lo, hi) {
  y <- runif(1, lo, hi)
  if(y < 0.75) {
    stop("y is less than 0.75")
  }
  y
}
safe_random <- safely(random)
safe_random() # will sometimes work, will sometimes return NULL
safe_random(0, 10) # will usually work
```

In you case, you want to modify the `google_geocode()` function.

```
safe_google_geocode <- safely(google_geocode)
```

Then loop over addresses calling this.

```
geocodes <- lapply( # purrr::map() is an alternative
  addresses,
  safe_google_geocode,
  key = "myapikey", 
  language = "ru", 
  simplify = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why you used `this_env <- environment()`? The environments are a bit complex here, and I'm having trouble following how the result moves from the closure created by the safely() function to the global environment in order to be assigned to an object.

Comment: @SeanNorton Yeah, it is confusing. `tryCatch()` seems to use its own environment, so just doing `result <- fn(...)` doesn't work.

Comment: @SeanNorton `this_env` is, I think, the environment belonging to the `safe_whatever()` closure.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately the assign() doesn't appear to be working correctly - I receive the error `In assign("result", fn(...), envir = this_env) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation` for every iteration, returning a list of entirely null elements. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: @SeanNorton Hmm. I'm not sure where the problem occurs. Does evaluating `fn(...)` with `eval.parent()` help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/20596902/134830

Comment: No, wrapping it in eval.parent() produces the same problem.

Comment: Strangely, after clearing my environment and reloading only the necessary packages (readxl, googleway), the code now appears to be running. I can only assume there was some sort of conflict with one of the packages or a bug of some sort, but I'm at a loss for what it could be.