# open.connection failing in geocoding function

Tags: r, permissions, google-places-api, handshake, windows-firewall

I'm currently running a geocoding function (using the `google_places` function in the `googleway` package). The function will run for a while (I have almost 3k locations), then throw the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.
```

Having consulted the system event log, I found the following information:

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}
 and APPID 
{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}
```

I'm not really sure what to do with this information. From my limited knowledge, it appears this is some sort of security/firewall issue. How should I go about giving R the permissions needed to run this function?

I am running Windows 10 with Windows Defender as antivirus/firewall. For reference, this is the function I am using for geocoding:

```
metro.locater <- function(lat, lon){

  library(googleway)

  #putting latitude and longitude into the same vector
  latlon <- c(lat, lon)

  #getting places result
  res <- google_places(location = latlon, 
                       place_type = "subway_station", radius = 50000,
                       rankby="distance",
                       key = "myKey")
  #condition handling
  if(res$status == 'OK'){
  closest <- res$results[1:3, ]

  return(closest)} else {
  try(return(res$status))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using an adverb I'd used with another geocoding function that attempts to run the function 5 times when it fails to provide results. Given that this worked, it seems likely that this was just a transient error rather than a systemic issue.

The adverb I used:

```
safely <- function(fn, ..., max_attempts = 5) {
  function(...) {
    this_env <- environment()
    for(i in seq_len(max_attempts)) {
      ok <- tryCatch({
          assign("result", fn(...), envir = this_env)
          TRUE
        },
        error = function(e) {
          FALSE
        }
      )
      if(ok) {
        return(this_env$result)
      }
    }
    msg <- sprintf(
      "%s failed after %d tries; returning NULL.",
      deparse(match.call()),
      max_attempts
    )
    warning(msg)
    NULL
  }
}
```

Taken from [Repeating values in loop until error disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486388/repeating-values-in-loop-until-error-disappears).