# Meaning of this warning; "Warning message: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation"

Tags: r, error-handling, warnings

I have written a function in R which extracts data from a database and builds a new table.

My new table is labeled with the date of the extract (`build_date_0`).

When I'm debugging my function I get the following warning when I look at my date string:

```
Browse[2]> build_date_0
[1] "2019-05-01"
Warning message:
In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

Questions:

1. What does this warning mean / what is happening (step-by-step/basics)?
2. Should I care?
3. In general how can I find out more about this error?

This is my code:

```
build_account_db = function(conn = connection_object
                            ,various_inputs = 24){
browser()

# create connection objects
tabs_1 = dplyr::tbl(conn,in_schema("DB_1","VIEW_W") # some table

# create date string
  build_date_0 = lubridate::today() %>% as.character()
  build_date = str_replace_all(build_date_0,"-+","_")
  db_name_1 = paste0('DATABASE.tab_1_',build_date)
  db_name_2 = paste0('DATABASE.tab_2_',build_date)

# build query
query_text_1 = tabs_1 %>% select(COL_1) # some query
query_text_1 = tabs_1 %>% select(COL_2)

# build new tables
create_db = DBI::dbSendQuery(conn_t,paste('CREATE TABLE',db_name_1,'AS (',query_text_1,') WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (ID_1)'))
create_db2 = DBI::dbSendQuery(conn_t,paste('CREATE TABLE',db_name_2,'AS (',query_text_2,') WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (ID_1)'))

}
```

When I check a variable, I may or may not get this warning (it varies, even if I restart R, and run my code again with a cleared environment)

```
Browse[2]> build_date
[1] "2019-02-28 11:00:00 AEDT"
Warning message:
In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

What I've tried: [I read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596902/r-avoiding-restarting-interrupted-promise-evaluation-warning), but it's more about suppressing the error. Also, google.

Comment: Did you get any advance on this matter? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: No, I haven't come across the issue in a while either (on a different project).

Answer (score 2):

I found this link on promises and evaluation in R helpful for a related problem: https://mailund.dk/posts/promises-and-lazy-evaluation/. I wonder if after `build_date_0 = lubridate::today() %>% as.character()` if you add a call to just `build_date_0` if that would solve the promise? Good luck!